# I have contenteditable div , and inside it is a noneditable span, how to be able to mark the div's text with a long click thrugh the span text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

I have contenteditable div , and inside it is a noneditable span,what should I do to be able to select the div's text with a long swing click starting on the the span text, and stop at the text I want to select?
I want to only select the text inside the div but NOT the text inside the noneditable span

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
span{
  color:lightgrey;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-message">
  <div contenteditable ='true'>
  some editable text
  <span class="main-search-placeholder" contenteditable="false" style="-moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select:none; user-select:none;-o-user-select:none;"  
   unselectable = "on" 
   onselectstart = "return false;" 
   onmousedown = "return false;"> 
  some other noneditable text
</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:
what i mean is i want to be able to select the text even if my mousedown has been clicked on the span area and then select the amount of characters inside the editabel text

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what you want.

Comment: the progblem i got that is the editable text is not being selected once my mousedown starts from the noneditable span... i just want it to be selected event if i mousedown when i was on the noneditable and normal functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS**

- Remove the focus outline of the `contentEditable` outer `div`
- Surround the editable part with an element
- When focused in the outer div with `contentEditable='true'`, show the focus outline on the editable region only

**JS**

- I set long press to 1 second (adjustable)
- You will have the exciting task of allowing *only* long clicks into the element
- To test it, click anywhere on the outer div (`#banner-message`) and you should see the focus on only the editable part of the text

```css
[contenteditable ='true']:focus {
  outline: none;
}

[contenteditable ='true'] .editable {
  display: inline-block;
}

[contenteditable ='true']:focus .editable {
  outline: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

**Gif**

At the beginning of the `gif`, I'm clicking on the non-editable part of the content and nothing happens. Then, at the end of the `gif`, I'm long-clicking on the outer `div` to show selection of text is working in the proper place.

[image]

**Demo:**

```js
var pressTimer;
var bannerMessage = document.getElementById("banner-message");
var editableRegion = bannerMessage.querySelector("[contenteditable ='true'] .editable");

function handleMouseUp() {
  clearTimeout(pressTimer);
  return false;
}

function handleMouseDown() {
  pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {

    if (document.body.createTextRange) {
      const range = document.body.createTextRange();
      range.moveToElementText(editableRegion);
      range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
      var selection = window.getSelection();
      var range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(editableRegion);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
    }
  }, 1000);
  return false;
}

bannerMessage.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
bannerMessage.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

span {
  color: lightgrey;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
}

[contenteditable='true']:focus {
  outline: none;
}

[contenteditable='true'] .editable {
  display: inline-block;
}

[contenteditable='true']:focus .editable {
  outline: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-message">
  <div contenteditable='true'>
    <div tabindex="-1" class="editable">some editable text</div>
    <span class="main-search-placeholder" contenteditable="false" style="-moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select:none; user-select:none;-o-user-select:none;" unselectable="on" onselectstart="return false;" onmousedown="return false;"> 
  some other noneditable text
</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have updated my question, but thanks alot! sorry for my lack of explaination....

Comment: @adirabargil Great to hear that.